# Problem running .exe file

Tags: wine

I installed `wine` from software center, but when I execute `.exe` file, it shows this message :

```
Err:module:import_dll Library MSVBVM60.DLL
```

So I downloaded dll fixer , but it gives an error when i run it !!

Comment: Read here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144183

Comment: mmm i see it , but it's seem does not help me to solve this problem .....!!!

Comment: Then read here: http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=15789

Comment: I am also getting this issue. I have read the two links above, but still doesn't help me. I have installed `winetricks`, but when I run the Windows program through Wine, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

downlaod the missing dll and copy it to your wine system32 foler.

go Home > ctrl+h > .wine > windows > system32 > (paste the missing dll that you downloaded.

if another error poped out and looking for another dll download it and do the same thing above.

i hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks 
sudo chmod +x winetricks 
sudo mv -v winetricks /usr/local/bin 
winetricks vb6run
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).